# Compare two files line by line and find the largest and smallest number using shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have two files which both have one number per line and need to compare both files to find the largest and smallest numbers.

eg:-

file1

```
2
34
5
```

file2

```
44
5
66
4
```

need to get 66 as largest number and 2 as smallest number.

If anyone guides me about the commands i need to focus on, that will be a grate help as I just started to learn shell scripting.

Comment: If not code at least provide a sample of your input and output.

Comment: Do you need to find one largest and one smallest out of all the numbers from two files ?

Comment: yes, and each line contains only one number in both files

Comment: So then the title is misleading, and there's no "line by line" comparison needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
sort -n file1 file2 > _sorted.tmp
min=$(head -1 _sorted.tmp)
max=$(tail -1 _sorted.tmp)
```

**Without temporary file:**

```
arr=( $(sort -n file1 file2) )
min=${arr[1]}
max=${arr[@]:(-1)}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually in 2 minds whether to write such a simple answer or not :)

Comment: Ah sorry for overlooking that, its fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Chain reaction:

```
sort --numeric --unique nu1 nu2 | sed '/^$/d' | sed -n '1p;$p'
 |      |         |      |  |            |           |   |  |
 |      |         |      |  |            |           |   |  +---- print last
 |      |         |      |  |            |           |   +------- print first
 |      |         |      |  |            |           +----------- no print
 |      |         |      |  |            +----------------------- remove empty
 |      |         |      |  +------------------------------------ file2
 |      |         |      +--------------------------------------- file1
 |      |         +---------------------------------------------- unique
 |      +-------------------------------------------------------- numeric
 +--------------------------------------------------------------- sort
```

The `sed '/^$/d'` part can be removed if you are 100% sure there are no empty lines in any of the files. If so, then `unique` can also be removed from `sort`.

In other words, meeting those two criterias this also works:

```
sort --numeric nu1 nu2 | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

As in short version:

```
sort -n nu1 nu2 | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be one liner too if you do not want to store the value

sort -n file1 file2 | head -1
sort -n file1 file2 | tail -1

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ head f1 f2
==> f1 <==
10
32
14

==> f2 <==
9
42
4
```

```
$ awk 'NR==1{min=$1;max=$1}
{max=(max>$1)?max:$1;min=(min<$1)?min:$1}
END{print "max is: "max; print "min is: "min}' f1 f2
max is: 42
min is: 4
```